# Difference in outputs using cumsum

Tags: r, lubridate, cumsum

Why are these two operations different?

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

> seconds_to_period(1:1000) %>% cumsum %>% sum
[1] 14492440
> 1:1000 %>% cumsum %>% sum
[1] 167167000
```

I have seen, however, that the issue lies on the fact that `cumsum` **only adds the seconds of the period and ignores the rest**:

```
seconds_to_period(60) +  seconds_to_period(60)
[1] "2M 0S"
```

but

```
> cumsum(c(seconds_to_period(60), seconds_to_period(60)))
[1] 0 0
```

Why is this behavior the default form? I think it is rather unintuitive. Additionally, what is the way to overcome this and get as a result the same as `cumsum(1:1000)` using 'Period' classes of lubridate that doesn't involve doing something like:

`c(seconds_to_period(60), seconds_to_period(60)) %>% as.numeric %>% cumsum`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being `cumsum`a primitive, you can see here https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-r-open/blob/master/source/src/main/cum.c what `R` it is doing under the hood. Moreover, if you read from line 215:

```
PROTECT(t = coerceVector(CAR(args), REALSXP));
    n = XLENGTH(t);
    PROTECT(s = allocVector(REALSXP, n));
    setAttrib(s, R_NamesSymbol, getAttrib(t, R_NamesSymbol));
    UNPROTECT(2);
```

This it is doing the coercion from `period` to `numeric` and because the structure of period, it is only keeping `.Data`

Compare

```
seconds_to_period(60)@.Data
seconds_to_period(59)@.Data
```

Therefore, at C level, R is not doing `as.numeric` but a faster, more efficient (but you may say less subtle because it is not realizing others elements from `.Data` as `as.numeric`does) coercion of data.

Look as this:

```
 setClass("Foo", representation(.Data="numeric", number1 = "numeric", number2 = "numeric"))

 bar <- new("Foo",.Data=5, number1 = 12, number2 = 31)

 cumsum(bar)
```

The result is 5, because it is only coercing to `numeric` `Data`

Moreover:

```
 setClass("Foo2", representation(.Data="numeric", number1 = "numeric", number2 = "numeric"))

 bar2 <- new("Foo2", number1 = 12, number2 = 31)

 cumsum(bar2)
```

Give you back `numeric(0)` because there is no `.Data`

And

```
 setClass("Foo3", representation( number1 = "numeric", number2 = "numeric"))

 bar3 <- new("Foo3", number1 = 12, number2 = 31)

 cumsum(bar3)
```

This is not working at all: without `.Data`, internally, R does not know how to coerce it to `numeric` when doing `cumsum`

So: it is because of how `R` internally works with complex S4 objects.
You can always tell the `lubridate` people to create a new parameter `seconds` and store in `.Data` the cumulative seconds of the whole S4 object. I guess this way `cumsum` will work. But right now, the are using `.Data` to store the second argument. See `edit(seconds_to_period)`:

```
function (x) 
{
  span <- as.double(x)
  remainder <- abs(span)
  newper <- period(second = rep(0, length(x)))
  slot(newper, "day") <- remainder%/%(3600 * 24)
  remainder <- remainder%%(3600 * 24)
  slot(newper, "hour") <- remainder%/%(3600)
  remainder <- remainder%%(3600)
  slot(newper, "minute") <- remainder%/%(60)
  slot(newper, ".Data") <- remainder%%(60)
  newper * sign(span)
}
```

Finally, just for fun. This is my mock version of how to make `cumsum` work here:

```
setClass("Period2",representation(.Data="numeric", period="Period"))


seconds_to_period_2 <- function(x){
   (lapply(x, function(y) new("Period2", .Data=y, period=seconds_to_period(y))))
}

a<-seconds_to_period_2(1:60)

cumsum(a)
```

Best!

Comment: I'm really proud of this community and answers like this one. I learned a lot with it, thank you!